# How to replace url with php

Tags: php, preg-replace

How to replace url with php
why this code not work .
please help

```
$mylogo = 'http://example.com/images/logo.png';
 $inputmylogo = 'http://example.com/image.png';
 $file = 'setting.php';
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    var_dump(preg_replace('/'.$mylogo.'/', $inputmylogo, $content));
```

Comment: use `str_replace()` Reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You want to employ str_replace here:

```
$mylogo = 'http://example.com/images/logo.png';
$inputmylogo = 'http://example.com/image.png';
$file = 'setting.php';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
var_dump(str_replace('/'.$mylogo.'/', $inputmylogo, $content));
```